# some confusion regarding meromorphic function?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin z} $ is     meromorphic  Since the poles of a meromorphic function are isolated,

Now  my confusion is that

Is  $\tan z$  is meromorphic?

My attempt : No  because  at  $z= \pi / 2$  is  non isolated

Is it true ?

Comment: You seem to have two different functions: $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ and $\tan z$. Which of these functions are you asking about?

Comment: @TobyMak im talking about $tanz$

Comment: Thanks, I just got confused because you mentioned a totally different function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

While there is a pole when $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$, that pole is isolated, because what it means to have an "isolated" pole is that, if you take a region surrounding that pole that is suitably small, yet *not zero* in size, there will be no other poles but the one you are taking the surroundings of.

And that's the case here: the next poles over are at $z = \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi$ and $z = \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi$. Hence, any circle of radius smaller than $\pi$ around this pole - or around any of the others - will contain no other poles. Thus, these poles are isolated. A pole can only be non-isolated if there are other ones crowding up *infinitely* dense there.

Abundance of poles and isolation of poles are not the same thing.

Comment: thanks u @The_sympathizer   one more  doubt  Is $ \tan (1/z) $ is  meromorphics ?

Comment: @jasmine : :) #mehhr. For that one - no - and in fact, that's actually a great illustration of these principles: There is a singularity now at $z = 0$, but it is _not_ isolated as there are infinitely many poles in any region thereabout, no matter how small you make it. The poles "bunch up infinitely hard cruckt" there, and thus it is not meromorphic.

Comment: thanks  u so much @The_Symapthizer  i was thinking same,,,,but  i was  not sure   so i asked u

Comment: @jasmine : :) you're welcome. :) #Mehhr.

Answer (score 2):

Another definition of a [meromorphic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeromorphicFunction.html) is that if $f(z) = \frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, and both $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ are entire.

Since $g(z) = 1$ which is a polynomial, and $h(z) = \sin x$ which is entire, then $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function. You can do the same for $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ as well.

Comment: Can you please accept the other answer? I know nothing about meromorphic functions and the other answer shows way more understanding of the topic than I do.